# Sprite menu, website example

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a question about a sprite menu. Would it be possible to make a sprite image like this:

?

What i am looking for is a menu that uses that image, and shows it everything i hover the link.

My problem is that when i try to do it, the text becomes unclickable :/ as u can see i allready tried with some css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to learn more about html / css layers (z-index):

http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm

http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php